# dense horizontal values of plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a group in R. The code looks like this. Each of RRA data frames is a time series.

```
lst <- list( RRA_36, RRA_48 , RRA_60 , RRA_72 )

lst %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "Window_Size") %>%
  ggplot2.lineplot( xName='Horizon', yName='RRA', groupName= "Window_Size" )
```

The result is this plot:

[image]

The horizontal axe is the dates of corresponding values. As you can see, ggplot2 writes the dates so much dense that it becomes unreadable. How can I plot this with a more readable and beautiful manner?

-ps. I have another question. How can I change this 'id' names to write something instead of these 1,2,3,4 numbers in legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,
`lst %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "Window_Size") %>%
  ggplot2.lineplot( xName='Horizon', yName='RRA', groupName= "Window_Size" ) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust=0.2))`

Comment: This makes things a little bit better, but still, it is too dense. Is there any way to write every other one of them? Also what about the other question about legends?

Comment: Since i canot see your data types, not sure which one will work for you but you can try around. if your legend is color legend then you can add this one ` + scale_color_discrete(labels=c("A", "b", "c","D")) for the legends`, I'm assuming you treat the time value as factors and ploted every points, you need to change your x into time format.

Comment: lst %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "Window_Size") %>% ggplot(aes(x=Horizon,y=RRA,color=Window_Size,group=Window_Size)) + geom_line() +
  scale_color_discrete(labels=c("A", "b", "c","D"))

Comment: Re: Jeremy M. , It changed the label angle on the x axis